# UnicodeEncodeError -- utf8 and unicode() not working

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I have a synopsis as follows:

```
synopsis = 'Eine Geschichte, wie im normalen Leben... Der als äußerst vorsichtig 
            geltende Risikoanalytiker Ruben verlässt seine Frau,...'
```

I am trying to write this to a file, but keep running into:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 705: ordinal not in range(128)

Here is what I've tried:

```
synopsis = unicode(synopsis)
new_file.write('%s' % synopsis)

synopsis = synopsis.encode('utf-8')
new_file.write('%s' % synopsis)
```

In addition, I have `# # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` specified at the top of my file.

Why is this occurring and how can I fix it?

Comment: you should use codecs.open() to write unicode text and use u'' for strings or 'text'.decode('utf-8')

Comment: Could you please show how this would be done in an answer?

Comment: http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/

Comment: yes sorry, try a = u'mytext' or 'mytextutf8'.decode('utf-8'), this gives you an unicode string, you can write an unicode string using codecs.open('dest', 'w', 'utf-8').write(myunicodestring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you opening `new_file`?

```
import codecs
new_file = codecs.open('out', mode='w', encoding='utf-8')
```

This should allow you to write Unicode strings to the file, which will be encoded as UTF-8.

(Unless otherwise set, `sys.getdefaultencoding()` is `'ascii'`, which affects the encoding of newly-opened files.)